# How do you check if a page is open in a dialog context?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using JSF and Primefaces' dialog framework to open a dialog on a button click. I have an xhtml page that can be opened in both it's own page and within a dialog. Is there a way, within a managed bean call to check if the RequestContext is from a dialog?

Something like:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().isDialogContext();
```

and then conditionally invoke:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check a specific request parameter.

It's a `GET` param, and it's appended by the script that launches the dialog on the contained iframe URL.

Check [DialogNavigationHandler](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/application/DialogNavigationHandler.java) for details.

```
public static boolean isDialogContext()
{
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext()
        .getRequestParameterMap()
        .containsKey(Constants.DIALOG_FRAMEWORK.CONVERSATION_PARAM);
}
```

where Constants is `org.primefaces.util.Constants`